# How to create dynamic resource file in asp.net mvc to import language for globalization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization, nopcommerce

I am developing multilingual web application in asp.net mvc that support language import functionality like "nopcommerce language install pack". In my application I am using two resource files, one for default English and other for French. Now I want to import third language dynamically so that it will create resource file and I can use this resource file in my application. So my question is how to create this resource file in my application dynamically? I will use xml file to import language whose format will be like this

[image]

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, you want to create the translated resouces files based on the English version?

Instead of creating and maintain the files manually, you can try to use online translation platform. For example, websites like OneSky can get your resources file dynamically created:

- Upload your English version .xml file
- Translate the resouce text (you can translate it yourselve by using the online editor, or order machine/ human translation)
- When you download the resources, the system will generate all the .xml files in different languages for you automatically

Hope it works for you.